# Json string fields and values to be listed for putting them in a table

Tags: java, string, json, list

```
{
  "statusCode": 1,
  "statusMessage": "Success",
  "meetingResults": {
  "meetingSearchResult": [
  {
    "meetingID": [
      {
        "value": "HE8-1MV",
        "systemCode": "31261"
      }
    ],
    "description": "MCR-COMIDA AGUILAR DE FRA.",
    "startDate": "2010-02-22T09:00:00",
    "endDate": "2010-02-22T09:00:00",
    "status": [
      "Approved"
    ],
    "owner": "KZRR616",
    "eventType": "Invitations",
    "venue": "SEVILLA",
    "location": "AGUILAR DE FRA."
  },
  {
    "meetingID": [
      {
        "value": "DE4-14L5",
        "systemCode": "31261"
      }
    ],
    "description": "1 SESIONES CLINICAS IRESSA 2010 01X081",
    "startDate": "2010-02-22T00:00:00",
    "endDate": "2010-02-22T00:00:00",
    "status": [
      "Approved"
    ],
    "owner": "KKZW742",
    "eventType": "AZ Regional Activity",
    "venue": "CORUÃ?A",
    "location": "ESPAÃ?A"
  },
  {
    "meetingID": [
      {
        "value": "K78-365",
        "systemCode": "31261"
      }
    ],
    "description": "FMF EDUARDO CADENAS",
    "startDate": "2010-02-22T09:00:00",
    "endDate": "2010-02-22T09:00:00",
    "status": [
      "Approved"
    ],
    "owner": "KTGC561",
    "eventType": "Invitations",
    "venue": "ALICANTE",
    "location": "ALICANTE"
  }
]
}
}
```

Is there a way/code to convert Json string to String array where every ids and values to be separated by Java program? I am looking this for list them one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, use [json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) to get easy access to json representation

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you intend to do with that data, it might be useful to create an Object representation of your data and work with it rather than working with a String array / Map of key/value pairs.

Gson library is very handy to convert back and forth between Java objects and JSON String. http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

The java objects you'll need will roughly look like:

```
public class MeetingID
{
    private String value;
    private String systemCode;
}

public class MeetingSearchResult
{
    private MeetingID meetingId;
    private String description;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private String status;
    private String owner;
    private String eventType;
    private String venue;
    private String location;
}

public class Response
{
    private int statusCode;
    private String statusMessage;
    private List<MeetingSearchResult> meetingResults;
}
```

And when you get a JSON String passed in to your java code, converting to Object is easy:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonStr = .... // Some JSON String
Response response = gson.fromJson(jsonStr); // magically convert from json String to Object
```

and the other way around:

```
Response response = ... // some response Object
String jsonStr = gson.toJson(response); // magically convert from an Object to its json representation
```